# sed over multiple files in multiple directories

Tags: sed

I have the following directory tree:

```
books>book(i)>cluster.pir
```

where book(i) are a set of sub directories 1 to 1023 each containing a folder called cluster.pir.

The following sed command:

```
sed -i '/>/d' ./*.pir
```

will delete any line in the file containing '>' for any file with a .pir ext, which is great, but my various .pir files are located in their own book(i) directory. How do I get the command to span across all the directories? I have tried:

```
find ./*.pir -type f -exec sed -i '/>/d' ./*.pir
```

when starting in the 'book' parent directory, but I get:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

does anyone have any thoughts on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The format for find is:

```
find -exec command {} \;
```

Where {} is replaced by the filename.

Edit: In your case this would become:

```
find ./*.pir -type f -exec sed -i '/>/d' {} \;
```

This will call sed on every file.

Comment: excellent thanks - although I had to do the following:

find -name "*.pir*" -type f -exec sed -i '/>/d' {} \; 

as it wouldn't find ./pir for some reason...

Answer (score 5):

You can add a wildcard to span all directories:

```
sed -i '/>/d' ./book*/*.pir
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having trouble using file wild-cards with sed on my Mac and this method worked fine:

```
FILE_PATH="/some/path/"
sed -i '' "s|search|replace|g"  $(find ${FILE_PATH} -name '*.ext')
```